# VB.Net DataGridView BindingSource and Structure Array not updating

Tags: vb.net, arrays, datagridview, structure, bindingsource

I'm having some issues and it's all explained in some simplified code

I have a structure

```
Public Structure myStruct
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property span As Double
    Public Property offs As Double
End Structure
```

Which is instantiated in a Singleton object as follow

```
Public myValues(10) As myStruct
```

Then on a form, I'm using the structure as the DataSource for a SourceBinder and the binder as DataSource for a DataGridView.

On loading the form, I get all the values into the binder

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        binder.Add(singleton.getRef.myValues(i))
    Next i
```

All the values are shown on the grid.

User is supposed to be able to change the values, which should reflect on myValues but no matter, what code I put on CellValueChanged or CurrentChanged. I can't make it reflect the changes.

Using breakbpoints on those events, I noticed that grid.row().cell().values and binder.current never changes.

I tried also placing a button and directly changing myValues and reseting the binder `binder.ResetBindings(False)` and nothing happens.

As far as I saw all ReadOnly properties are set to false.

I've also tried setting VirtualMode to true on the grid and catching CellValuePushed and CellValueNeeded events but those are never called. (that was on a guessing base)

I'm really out of ideas on this one, if anyone can help me!

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a class instead:

```
Public Class myStruct
  Public Property name As String
  Public Property span As Double
  Public Property offs As Double
End Class
```

Comment: After I posted this question yesterday and went home from work I was thinking about it and had a hint it would be something like this.
Apparently Structures are passed ByVal and there's not much I can do about it. 
A bit weird to create a class just to have r/w properties but ok.
Does anyone know if there's any disadvantage on it?

Comment: @Budius I find it rare to use Structures for exactly that reason.  BTW, a class that does databinding should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  See [How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)